# jQuery toggle animation confliting with class

Tags: jquery

Hi i am not able to toggle this function, it is working at once but after that fade up. help me out of it.....

```
$(".toggle_btn a").click (function() {

        $(".toggle_btn").addClass("toggle_btn_active");  
        $("#left_content").animate({width:"270px"},150);
        $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"280px"},150);
        $(".left_navigation").removeClass("sml");

        $(".toggle_btn_active a").click (function() {
            $(".toggle_btn").removeClass("toggle_btn_active");  
            $("#left_content").animate({width:"60px"},150);
            $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"70px"},150);
            $(".left_navigation").addClass("sml");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Post your html code as well

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".toggle_btn a").click (function() {
    $(".toggle_btn").addClass("toggle_btn_active");  
    $("#left_content").animate({width:"270px"},150);
    $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"280px"},150);
    $(".left_navigation").removeClass("sml");
});

$(document).on ('click', ".toggle_btn_active a", function() {
    $(".toggle_btn").removeClass("toggle_btn_active");  
    $("#left_content").animate({width:"60px"},150);
    $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"70px"},150);
    $(".left_navigation").addClass("sml");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a click handler inside a click callback...

What this does is bind another event every time you click `.toggle_btn a`. i.e, if you click it 3 times, you will have bound 3 `.toggle_btn_active a` handlers.

you should separate the bindings and bind them using the [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which allows you to bind events to elements that don't yet exist in the dom.

For that to work, you would need to bind the event to an existing parent of the element you're changing.

```
    $(".parent").on('click', '.toggle_btn a',function() {
        $(".toggle_btn").addClass("toggle_btn_active");  
        $("#left_content").animate({width:"270px"},150);
        $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"280px"},150);
        $(".left_navigation").removeClass("sml");
    });
    $(".parent").on('click', '.toggle_btn_active a',function() {
        $(".toggle_btn").removeClass("toggle_btn_active");  
        $("#left_content").animate({width:"60px"},150);
        $("#main_container").animate({"margin-left":"70px"},150);
        $(".left_navigation").addClass("sml");
    });
```